# Responsive gui customtkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

My GUI application is not responsive, **I want it to resize according to the window size.**

Currently am using .`place(x,y)` for placing components.

Example:

```
label.place(x=100,y=50)
```

[Current components when windows maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0mvp.png)

Tried looking for a solution, and was informed of `.pack()` method for placing component, it has 2 paramas relative x (relx) and relative y (rely) in respect to its frame/master. Tested it out but still my GUI app isn't .responsive.

Comment: What does "not responsive" mean in that context ? What do you expect and what happens instead ?

Comment: It is hard to create responsive GUI using `place()`.  Post what you have tried on using `pack()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `.place(x, y)` method always places a widget at the same spot.

If you want it to change when the window is resized you should add this line to your code:

```py
root.bind("<Configure>", change_size)
```

Where change_size is a function which can be used to modify the widgets placement / size to match the window's size.

If you need the width and height of the window in the change_size function (you probably need those), this is the way to obtain them:

```py
width = win.winfo_width()
height = win.winfo_height()
```

Hope I helped you, have a nice day.

Comment: So this is something like media query ? whenever window is  resized first see the width and height and then , I have to specify/change positions of my gui components ?

Comment: Yep, that is the solution is use in my projects